# Use 3 monitors w/built-in intel adapter + two old nvidia PCI cards on 10.10?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

I'd like to move from windows with my current workstation. The only thing holding me back is that I have **3** monitors connected to the system and I really take advantage of the real estate when working.

I just installed *Ubuntu 10.10* on the system and one of the monitors is up and running just fine. This monitor is connected to the built-in *Intel* adapter. I also have two old *nVidia GeForce4 MX 4000* (*nv19pl*) cards in my two PCI slots with two  monitors connected to them respectively. I installed the legacy (and proprietary) nVidia drivers (the *nvidia-96* package) that claims to support these old cards.

Now the question is how to get *X* configured to use all adapters (using two different drivers) so I can use all three monitors (and is this even possible)?

From what I've read, it looks like I'll have to write an *xorg.conf* file since the nVidia driver doesn't support the auto-magic configuration supported by other drivers. On this site:

http://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

it says that on *10.10* I just need to write an *xorg.conf* "*containing only those sections and options that you need to override Xorg's autoconfigurated settings*".

So, does this mean I can get away with only including the nVidia-specific configuration stuff and all else will get auto-configured? Or, will providing a config with a "*Device*" section overrule the auto-magic from detecting/using the *Intel* adapter?

I ran the included *nvidia-xconfig* to generate a basic, nVidia-specific *xorg.conf* but I'm hesitant to reboot with it in place, suspecting I'll have a screwed up display. Also, is there any way (any tool or command) to generate an *xorg.conf* from the current, auto-configured running state of an *X* session? If I have to write a full, complete config, I'd rather start with one that includes everything that's been auto-detected thus far (and merge it with my nVidia version).

Anyhow, any info and thoughts are greatly appreciated (as are answers).

Comment: So after taking koanhead's recommendation and ensuring Ctrl+Alt+F1 works (and installing openssh-server) I merged the xorg.conf files created by running _nvidia-xconfig_ and _Xorg -configure_ respectively. It is here: http://gist.github.com/780036 (and it doesn't work, see my next commment).

Comment: The result of restarting w/the above config is logged here: (http://gist.github.com/780041). The intel card _works_ but not completely (more on this later). However, it appears that it can't even load the _nvidia_ driver: (line 129) "undefined symbol: miEmptyData". So, any ideas why the driver can't even load? (I know this is technically a separate question, but it is related to my overall, general question too).

Comment: Well, after reading this post: (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566254) and other linked resource, and looking at the nvidia "Release Highlights" on their driver download page here: (http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-96.43.19-driver.html) it looks like the driver in the nvidia-97 package is already out of date and never even supported X.Org Server version 1.9.0. Soooo, before I can do anything it looks like I'll need to test out manually upgrading to the latest nvidia driver. I'll post my results...

Comment: meta-advice: comments like the ones you've added are normally appended to the question with a heading like **update**.  This helps keep the comments thread clear, and also I think bumps your question on the hotlist.

Answer (score 1):

First, nvidia-xconfig will have saved a backup of your original xorg.conf file. You might check that this is so before proceeding, but even if it didn't keep a backup the old file is most likely the default anyway.

Next, if you restart X and the display is broken, make sure that you can get to another console and / or kill the X server. I recommend you test whether Ctrl+Alt+F2 works to switch to another console. It might also be a good idea to set up an ssh server on the machine if you haven't already, so that you can login even if the console is unresponsive (I've seen X misconfiguration cause X to ignore keyboard events).

Lastly, yes, there is a way to autogenerate a new xorg.conf file: delete the existing file and restart X. 
X will attempt to autodetect all settings and write an xorg.conf if it does not detect one.
If it turns out that the xorg.conf generated by nvidia-xconfig does not support the Intel device and the old xorg.conf does not support the nVidia devices, you can try to `diff` the new file against the old one and `patch` the differences into the old file.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the information was helpful. It's been so long since I've had to do any X configuration (late 90's early 2000's on FreeBSD machines) that I couldn't remember (or didn't even know) the key combo: Ctrl+Alt+F[X] to get my non-gui console. On another note, my newly install Ubuntu 10.10 system doesn't even have an actual xorg.conf file (sudo find / -name xorg.conf -ls) except an example one in /usr/share/doc/[somewhere]. It appears the system relies solely on auto-configuration by default. It also never generates an xorg.conf (except by manually running Xorg -configure)